# Existing engine for bouncing balls?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm looking at creating a game which involves many bouncing balls on the screen, and the user can sortof select one of those balls and take it out...

The balls should be able to bounce of eachother and the walls.

I've tried implementing this from scratch, following the tutorials at http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/vectors/tut11.html - but it's not quite working for me, and if I need the game to become more complicated- probably best to use an existing engine.

So is there an existing engine that will work very fast and well for this sort of thing? At a glance- it didn't seem like box2d or flixel would work for this... but what do you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many physics engine out there. Take a look at [APE](http://code.google.com/p/ape/). It's a bit old but very simple an efficient.

Comment: Accepted since the brief was "not box2d"... though APE looks pretty old ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bouncing grabbable balls on a screen? Box2d for Flash could definitely do that.

- http://www.box2dflash.org/
- http://www.kerp.net/box2d/